# Why encoding/json marshals slices as base64?

Tags: go

I am writing a SDK for a restful api. It has very very nested structure.

For example for a part of data.

```
type FieldUint8Options struct {
    MinValue  uint8   `json:"min_value"`
    MaxValue  uint8   `json:"max_value"`
    Step      uint    `json:"step"`
    Operation string  `json:"operation"`
    ValueList []uint8 `json:"value_list"`
}

type TTLOption struct {
    Value       uint8               `json:"value"`
    FieldEngine []FieldUint8Options `json:"field_engine"`
}
```

When i marshal initialized data of TTLOption struct, ValueList field turning base64 data.

Code:

```
jsonFile, err := os.Open("example.json")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(0)
}
    
byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

var ttl TTLOption
if err := json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &ttl); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(0)
}

// I also wrote Custom UnmarshalJSON() interface for TTLOption and FieldUint8Options to handle nil slices.
data, _ := json.Marshal(ttl)
fmt.Println(string(data))
```

Output:

```
'ttl': {'value': 123, 'field_engine': [{'min_value': 123, 'max_value': 222, 'step': 1, 'operation': 'random', 'value_list': 'ZA=='}]}}
```

As you can see value_list is base64 representation. Why it behave like this ?
Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://play.golang.org/p/taf4_Iofzp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the json marshaler doc says:

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte encodes as a base64-encoded string, and a nil slice encodes as the null JSON value.

`byte` is an alias for `uint8`.

You can use `uint` for marshaling purposes, and it will marshal as JSON array.